# how to do rsa encryption using publicKey.xml file in flutter dart , i am getting issue FormatException: Could not parse BigInt

Tags: c#, flutter, cryptography, public-key-encryption, pointycastle

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>D4ZblrI8NsZgnZOQbHJuEv7Lg0pCOuhwmGIS10rwlJ9Z/hGbes=</Modulus><Exponent>ABCD</Exponent><P>86TWhp553PrrlQ/xdOpGDbGy8/h3/5vg+P==</P><Q>D33zQmGtBnoO8OaQhCwbwqai1w==</Q><DP>i0RwPcLPh+WQKt5L75SR1PQ==</DP><DQ>3vayrPOJ1WMFxPzCpqMaUDWwWsBJ/c0PRwRhvrSw4/TR+6BlEkU/5b17/==</DQ><InverseQ>CbuGb8ZNvjCkSHqvSTJvFpFfqxxQjH09ABxBZx3K7SNvw3+6+LfKeRzoz7==</InverseQ><D>p6etDZ1ghROHdHWAauTUe6zn/RQzm7HE5aCWVOgMqcg9VkFMMZ3H+R1rec=</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

above you can see the sample format of my publicKey.xml file , i need to convert this into pem format for rsa encryption , mainly need to encrypt the username & password.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

void encryptRSa() {
  String publicKeyXML = '''
   <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>D4ZblrI8NsZgnZOQbHJuEv7Lg0pCOuhwmGIS10rwlJ9Z/hGbes=</Modulus><Exponent>ABCD</Exponent><P>86TWhp553PrrlQ/xdOpGDbGy8/h3/5vg+P==</P><Q>D33zQmGtBnoO8OaQhCwbwqai1w==</Q><DP>i0RwPcLPh+WQKt5L75SR1PQ==</DP><DQ>3vayrPOJ1WMFxPzCpqMaUDWwWsBJ/c0PRwRhvrSw4/TR+6BlEkU/5b17/==</DQ><InverseQ>CbuGb8ZNvjCkSHqvSTJvFpFfqxxQjH09ABxBZx3K7SNvw3+6+LfKeRzoz7==</InverseQ><D>p6etDZ1ghROHdHWAauTUe6zn/RQzm7HE5aCWVOgMqcg9VkFMMZ3H+R1rec=</D></RSAKeyValue>
  ''';

  var document = xml.XmlDocument.parse(publicKeyXML);
  var modulusBase64 = document.findAllElements('Modulus').single.text;
  var exponentBase64 = document.findAllElements('Exponent').single.text;

  var modulusBytes = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(modulusBase64));
  var exponentBytes = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(exponentBase64));

  var modulus = decodeBigIntFromBytes(modulusBytes);
  var exponent = decodeBigIntFromBytes(exponentBytes);

  var publicKey = RSAPublicKey(modulus, exponent);

  var encryptor = OAEPEncoding(RSAEngine())
    ..init(true, PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey));

  String message = 'Hello, World!';

  var encrypted = encryptor.process(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(message)));

  print('EncryptedOne: ${base64.encode(encrypted)}');
}

BigInt decodeBigIntFromBytes(Uint8List bytes) {
  return BigInt.parse(base64.encode(bytes), radix: 16);
}
```

i am using pointcastle & xml library for encryption , when i run this code i am getting the issue
FormatException: Could not parse BigInt

Comment: Although this question is far too broad, I think it's important to note that you've actually supplied an XML **private** key file in your question. That key is now forever compromised.

Comment: @ President James K. Polk actually this is not an  original key its just a sample format i have given

Comment: @President James K. Polk
its publicKey.xml not privateKey.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is that in the function `decodeBigIntFromBytes()` the data in `BigInt.parse()` is incorrectly Base64 encoded. Correct is a hex encoding, corresponding to the radix 16 used by you:

```dart
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
...
BigInt decodeBigIntFromBytes(Uint8List bytes) {
  return BigInt.parse(hex.encode(bytes), radix: 16);
}
```

With this change, the code works, both the import of the public key and the encryption itself.

---

Additional, but minor: Instead of the expired `text`, [`innerText`](https://pub.dev/documentation/xml/latest/xml/XmlStringExtension/innerText.html) should be used, e.g:

```dart
var modulusBase64 = document.findAllElements('Modulus').single.innerText;
```

---

If you want to export/import the key in PEM format, the [*basic_utils*](https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils#cryptoutils) package provides suitable functions, e.g. `CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPem()` can be used to export the public key PEM encoded in X.509/SPKI format:

```dart
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
...
print('X.509/SPKI, PEM: ${CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPem(publicKey)}');
```

---

Note that the posted key, as already noted in the comments, is indeed a *private* RSA key. A *public* key only contains `Modulus` and `Exponent` field (all other fields belong to the private key and must not be disclosed). However, since this is obviously a test key, disclosure is probably not critical.

---

Complete code with valid test key:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';

...

void encryptRSa() {

  // key import
  var publicKeyXML = '''<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>unF5aDa6HCfLMMI/MZLT5hDk304CU+ypFMFiBjowQdUMQKYHZ+fklB7GpLxCatxYJ/hZ7rjfHH3Klq20/Y1EbYDRopyTSfkrTzPzwsX4Ur/l25CtdQldhHCTMgwf/Ev/buBNobfzdZE+Dhdv5lQwKtjI43lDKvAi5kEet2TFwfJcJrBiRJeEcLfVgWTXGRQn7gngWKykUu5rS83eAU1xH9FLojQfyia89/EykiOO7/3UWwd+MATZ9HLjSx2/Lf3g2jr81eifEmYDlri/OZp4OhZu+0Bo1LXloCTe+vmIQ2YCX7EatUOuyQMt2Vwx4uV+d/A3DP6PtMGBKpF8St4iGw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>''';
  var xmlDocument = xml.XmlDocument.parse(publicKeyXML);
  var modulus = getData(xmlDocument, 'Modulus');
  var exponent = getData(xmlDocument, 'Exponent');
  var publicKey = RSAPublicKey(modulus, exponent);

  // encryption
  var message = 'Hello, World!';
  var encryptor = OAEPEncoding(RSAEngine())..init(true, PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey)); // Applies SHA-1 by default for both digests, i.e. the OAEP and MGF1 digest, and an empty label
  var encrypted = encryptor.process(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(message)));
  print('EncryptedOne: ${base64.encode(encrypted)}');

  // key export
  print('X.509/SPKI, PEM: ${CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPem(publicKey)}');
}

BigInt getData(xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument, String element){
  var dataB64 = xmlDocument.findAllElements(element).single.innerText;
  var dataBytes = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(dataB64));
  return BigInt.parse(hex.encode(dataBytes), radix: 16);
}
```

---

**Edit:** Regarding the question from the comment about importing the private key. The import of the private key is analogous. The elements `Modulus`, `D` (private exponent), `P` (prime 1) and `Q` (prime 2) are required. These values are used to instantiate `RSAPrivateKey`, which can then be applied for decryption.

Complete code with valid private key (associated with the public key from the encryption code):

```dart
...
// key import
var privateKeyXML = '''<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>unF5aDa6HCfLMMI/MZLT5hDk304CU+ypFMFiBjowQdUMQKYHZ+fklB7GpLxCatxYJ/hZ7rjfHH3Klq20/Y1EbYDRopyTSfkrTzPzwsX4Ur/l25CtdQldhHCTMgwf/Ev/buBNobfzdZE+Dhdv5lQwKtjI43lDKvAi5kEet2TFwfJcJrBiRJeEcLfVgWTXGRQn7gngWKykUu5rS83eAU1xH9FLojQfyia89/EykiOO7/3UWwd+MATZ9HLjSx2/Lf3g2jr81eifEmYDlri/OZp4OhZu+0Bo1LXloCTe+vmIQ2YCX7EatUOuyQMt2Vwx4uV+d/A3DP6PtMGBKpF8St4iGw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>3e+jND6OS6ofGYUN6G4RapHzuRAV8ux1C9eXMOdZFbcBehn/ydhzR48LIPTW9HiRE00um27lXfW5/POCaEUvfOp1UxTWeHZ4xICo40PBo383ZKW1MbES1oiMbjkEqSFGRnTItnLU07bKbzLA7I0UWHWCEAnv0g7HRxk973FAsm8=</P><Q>1w8+olZ2POBYeYgw1a0DkeJWKMQi/4pAgyYwustZo0dHlRXQT0OI9XQ0j1PZWoQS28tFcmoEAg6f5MUDpdM9swS0SOCPI1Lc/f/Slus3u1O3UCezk37pneSPezskDhvV2cClJEYH8m/zwDAUlEi4KLIt/H/jgtyDd6pbxxc78RU=</Q><DP>iE6VAxJknM4oeakBiL6JTdXEReY+RMu7e4F2518/lJmoe5CaTCL3cnzFTgFyQAYIvD0MIgSzNMkl6Ni6QEY1y1fIpTVIIAZLWAzZLXPA6yTIJbWsmo9xzXdiIJQ+a433NnClkYDne/xpSnB2kxJ263mIX0drFq1i8STsqDH7lVs=</DP><DQ>VqUJsxXqpTQt8Sjxo+UE3y21UM9U2me0/iHQ2DE9eA8rw+D6ADVRZLLgyi4aD+HOR0dqP2J/IuUJfn3xrkmhPhLTH9l5Ud38s0jya2NxHMPpwx17uB0Vuktvk1KMgDKuwgBfiHG+meqI5hF4+RUjPSIsbOKJoxt8zCWSvG+b8tE=</DQ><InverseQ>s9Fu1JsTak+C84codMY+vuApuaxZVs5xADysbzTVPfxb9Q97Ve3KcwSPPNDb05pV5DC9Q334PEVcnpi/CPqKHhZ2rXT2Ls6jV8OcxzM5A30MpyHZ40Aes1I4zIsMIGb77BvIcCxLZPRU7z6DMsAG+JmbkAUJBZ+R7gtmjmY5LXQ=</InverseQ><D>SlJj0ExIomKmmBhG8q8SM1s2sWG6gdQMjs6MEeluRT/1c2v79cq2Dum5y/+UBl8x8TUKPKSLpCLs+GXkiVKgHXrFlqoN+OYQArG2EUWzuODwczdYPhhupBXwR3oX4g41k/BsYfQfZBVzBFEJdWrIDLyAUFWNlfdGIj2BTiAoySfyqmamvmW8bsvc8coiGlZ28UC85/Xqx9wOzjeGoRkCH7PcTMlc9F7SxSthwX/k1VBXmNOHa+HzGOgO/W3k1LDqJbq2wKjZTW3iVEg2VodjxgBLMm0MueSGoI6IuaZSPMyFEM3gGvC2+cDBI2SL/amhiTUa/VDlTVw/IKbSuar9uQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>''';
var xmlDocument = xml.XmlDocument.parse(privateKeyXML);
var modulus = getData(xmlDocument, 'Modulus');
var privateExponent = getData(xmlDocument, 'D');
var p = getData(xmlDocument, 'P');
var q = getData(xmlDocument, 'Q');
var privateKey = RSAPrivateKey(modulus, privateExponent, p, q);

var decryptor = OAEPEncoding(RSAEngine())..init(false, PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(privateKey)); // Applies SHA-1 by default for both digests, i.e. the OAEP and MGF1 digest, and an empty label
var decrypted = decryptor.process(base64.decode(encryptedBase64)); // encryptedBase64: Base64 encoded ciphertext

print('Decrypted data: ${utf8.decode(decrypted)}');

// key export
print('PKCS#8, PEM: ${CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPrivateKeyToPem(privateKey)}');
```

Comment: how to do the same approach in private key

Comment: also each time i am getting different cipher text for the same plain text encryption , i want same cipher for the same plain text , how to do that?

Comment: @Nns_ninteyFIve - Regarding comment 1: In your question, you talk about the public key and encryption. Encryption is performed with the public key, not with the private key. The private key is used for decryption. Importing the private key and decryption are completely analogous, see the **Edit** section of my answer.

Comment: @Nns_ninteyFIve - Regarding comment 2: RSA encryption is not deterministic for security reasons. Repeated encryption with the same key and the same plaintext generates different ciphertexts. This is due to padding. Without padding (textbook RSA) the same ciphertext would be generated, but this must not be used for security reasons (and is therefore not supported by most libraries). You may also be confusing this with signing/verifying, for which there are deterministic padding variants. For more details about this, please ask a new question.

Comment: i have used above code for publicKey encryption i have getting a cipher that is not working on my api side , its still shows unauthorised data , do we need any workaround on this code and also please share the decryption code  , so i need to check the cipher text is correct or not

Comment: you can check my edited question i have added the C# code used in server side

Comment: actually from the given code encryption is working , but the cipher text is not the right one i am getting , i have checked this cipher text with api , its not giving the token its shows unauthorised , so there is no use of this code for me

Comment: i will add this as a new issue, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Nns_ninteyFIve - I gave it a quick try. For me, encryption with the C# code works and so does decryption of the C#-ciphertext with the Dart code (if that's what you're concerned with). You should post in your new question which .NET version you are running (e.g. .NET 7) and post non-productive test data: key pair (here you can take my two test keys), plaintext and ciphertext generated with the C# code, which cannot be decrypted with the Dart code on your machine).

Comment: actually encryption is done from dart side i am passing these encrypted data to server side (C#) using api call and they check the encrypted text is from the given  public key and they decrypt it from there side, here i am getting issue with the encrypted text i am passing to server side(C#) , i think the server side using different format for decryption. i need to encrypt the data using  format that the server side uses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255868/discussion-between-nns-ninteyfive-and-topaco).